# How can a proton in a nucleus decay into neutron and positron in β+ decay if neutrons have greater mass than a proton?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity, binding-energy, elements

I'm guessing it has something to do with mass defect/binding energy??

Comment: A free proton never (as far as we can tell) decays. The mass of a free proton is less than that of a neutron, so the free proton decay $p\rightarrow n+e^+ +\nu$ does not occur (also note that the positron and the neutrino also add to the total mass/energy of the decay products). However, protons inside a nuclei can decay - see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#%CE%B2+_decay). The resulting nucleus must have a  lower total energy than the original nucleus.

Comment: [Positron emission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron_emission) requires a nuclear transformation with at least the energy equivalent of the mass of two electrons.